# How could i execute another sql query on hyperlink click to display his whole details from DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

How would i fetch deyails from database using query string.I have a fetched and displayed the details, in HTML table using PHP.
The table look such in HTML table -

```
ID | NAME | Designatioon
........................
1 | ABC | Developer
2 | PQR | Tester
3 | XYZ | Developer
```

where - ABC would be a hyperlink. I would like to have some idea or skeleton where onClick of hyperlink it should execute another SQL query  and it should give the desired details of ABC.

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
   <table class="table table-hover">
   <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Designation</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
     <?php
    If(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {  
    $var1=$row['cand_number'];
    $var2=$row['cand_fname'];
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="viewcandidate.php?var=<?php echo urlencode($var1);?>"><?php echo urlencode($var1);?></a><td>
    <td><?php echo $row['cand_fname']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['cand_desc']; ?></td> 
    </tr>
    <?php

    }
    }
    ?>
   </tr>
</table>
```

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM candidate ".$join.' where '.$condition;


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
$FirstName  =$row['cand_fname']; 
$LastName=$row['cand_lname']; 
$Position =$row['cand_postion']; 
$Gender=$row['cand_gender']; 
}
```

On click "ABC" i.e the link...the above query should get executed. Correct us if I am wrong or suggest me some ideas ,how would i achieve this. Thank You.

Comment: Can you post viewcandidate.php page

Comment: @Codelord..Ok can you tell me how do display the details on different page as I have changed my mind to display the details into same page to next new page. Thank you.

Comment: Just you need to get candidate id from url query and then run query in php which will return candidate details which you will show in that page.

Comment: so can I post answer

Comment: @Codelord ..yes sure.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your current work just you need to get candidate id from url query and then run query in php which will return candidate details which you will show in that page.

This will solve your problem.